# Android - How to finish button if using setVisibility

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

I have buttons and they all finish to go to the next activity.

But I'm trying to finish an button that has setVisibility like example code below.

```
Button failfiveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.failfive);

failfiveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
          Button button = (Button) v;
          button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          mSoundManager.playSound(2);
          finish();
    }
});

Button failsixButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.failsix);

failsixButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
          Button button = (Button) v;
          button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          mSoundManager.playSound(2);
          finish();
     }
});
```

Because I have about six buttons of the code above and if I add `finish();` 
under `mSoundManager.playSound(2);` it goes back to the first .main screen. Instead of letting me continue and make the rest of the buttons invisible.

If I don't finish(); the application lags from too much memory leaking.

Thanks

Wahid

Comment: [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) method is from `Activity` class, not from `Button` class. If you want to make the Button invisible and clear its occupied space try `button.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its happening because this method gets called when ever a button is clicked. it does't care how many buttons you click. here you are finishing your Activity for each button click, so this is happening. a silly solution could be this

```
private static int count = 0;
private static int count1 = 0;
failfiveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
count++
         Button button = (Button) v;
         button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mSoundManager.playSound(2);
if(count == 6)
    finish();
}
});

    Button failsixButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.failsix);

        failsixButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View v) {
                  count1++
                 Button button = (Button) v;
                 button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mSoundManager.playSound(2);
if(count1==6)
            finish();
        }
        });
```

Edit: there could be other better ways to do it. but i gave you this solution since i don't know what exactly is your purpose.